# Cucumber data table "no implicit conversion of String into Integer"

Tags: cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

I have next cuke scenario:

```
  Scenario: Product page contains right bar.
    When right bar contains customization elements:
      | Color selection | Color |
```

And steps:

```
When(/^right bar contains customization elements\:$/) do |table|
  data = table.raw
  on(ProductPage) do |page|
    expect(page.div_element(text: data['Color selection']).present?).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

And I'm getting `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer`
on 
`expect(page.div_element(text: data['Color selection']).present?).to be_truthy`

Why? For other similar scenarios all are ok.

Comment: What are you trying to get with `data['Color selection']`? Are you trying to get the text 'Color'? If so, you want `data = table.row_hashes`. `table.raw` returns an Array of Arrays, which is why `[]` is expecting an Integer and not a String.

Comment: Aw, sure. Thanks.